# how to drop 1900 columns in python df.drop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

What's a good way to drop columns say 4 to 1952 with the 'df.drop' method?
I'm using beautifulsoup to pull data and converting to xml and it has 1952 columns.
thanks in advance!

```
table = soup.find('table')
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
t=[]
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text.rstrip('\n') for tr in td]
    t.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(t)
df = df.iloc[4:]
```

Answer (score 2):

Select only the columns you are interested in.

```
df = df[cols_of_interest]
```

or try this

```
df.drop([:,'Column 4':'Column 1952'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```